# Get non-valid fields from Django Form

Tags: django

Say I have the following view

```
def add_list(request):
   user = request.user
   if request.method =="POST":
      instance = MyModel(user=user)
      form = MyForm(instance = instance)
      form.is_valid()  #False
```

is there a way to figure out, which fields are "wrong" and why?

I tried `form.errors` which returned `{}`

Comment: Have you tried `form.non_field_errors` to see errors that are not related to any fields?

Comment: @Nimdeveloper: if a form is not *bounded* (by passing data), the form is not valid, so then the `.errors`, etc. are all empty.

Comment: Thats Empty aswell

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yep, that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Form` (`ModelForm` or a "simple" `Form`) is only valid if (1) it is bounded; and (2) if no validation errors pop up. A form is bounded if data is passed to it (which is usually the first parameter named `data`).

In order to make a form bounded, you thus should pass something to the `data=…` parameter, this can be an empty dictionary, or a `QueryDict` like `request.POST`.

We can thus for example pass the `request.POST` (and `request.FILES`) as first (two) parameters:

```
def add_list(request):
   if request.method =='POST':
      instance = MyModel(user=user)
      form = MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=instance)
      if form.is_valid():
          # … (likely form.save())
          pass
```

Comment: The thing is, the `request` contains data submitted by the user, which has to be transformed before added to `MyForm` along with some other data (I omitted that for clarity reasons), thus the request data has actually nothing to do in `MyForm`. Do I still need request.POST thne?

Comment: @CutePoison: A form is valid if it is *bounded* and has no field errors. A form is *bounded* if you pass data to it, for example `request.POST` or `request.GET` (for a search with  a GET request).

Comment: Then i'll need to bind it with my transformed data then I assume (parsing a data-dict instead of request.POST) ?

Comment: @CutePoison: `request.POST` *is* a `QueryDict`, so a dictionary-like object, but you can work with other dictionary(-like) objects.

Comment: Feel free to add to your answer, that the form has to be bound otherwise it cannot be valid - then I'll accept the answer

Comment: I generally struggle to find the docs for specific classes/functions in Django. Do you by any chance have the link to the Form class docs? Not a guide of how to use it, but what it takes as inputs etc. (I can only find guides like https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/)

Comment: @CutePoison: yes, that part is imho a bit "cryptic". In the documentation it says "*
    An unbound form has no data associated with it. When rendered to the user, it will be empty or will contain default values. (...) A bound form has submitted data, and hence can be used to tell if that data is valid.*" (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#bound-and-unbound-form-instances). But I agree that this is not very clear. I once checked the source code of a form for this: https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/forms.py#L173-L175