# Parsing data-dict vs. model-instance to Django ModelForm

Tags: django

Is there a difference between doing

```py
instance = MyModel()
form = MyModelForm(instance=instance)
form.save(commit = False)
form.instance.foo="foo"
form.instance.bar="bar"
form.save()
```

and

```py
data = {"foo":"foo","bar":"bar"}
form = MyForm(data=data)
form.save()
```

when creating an object?

Answer (score 0):

When we pass an `instance` to a form we indicate to the form that we want to *update* this instance, the form also helpfully uses the instance to populate itself with initial data.

Whereas when we pass `data` to the form it entails user submitted data and is what makes a form *bound* or *unbound*. To explain this concept I would quote a few lines from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#bound-and-unbound-forms):

> A **Form** instance is either **bound** to a set of data, or
> **unbound**.
>
> - If it’s **bound** to a set of data, it’s capable of validating that data and rendering the form as HTML with the data displayed in the
>   HTML.
> - If it’s **unbound**, it cannot do validation (because there’s no data to validate!), but it can still render the blank form as HTML.

Hence `instance` and `data` are two different things. Essentially your first snippet is useless, as you aren't performing any cleaning / validation, whereas in your second snippet you are performing cleaning and validation *but* you are creating a new instance. You can pass both kwargs together to update a model instance:

```
instance = MyModel.objects.get(pk=some_pk)
data = {"foo":"foo","bar":"bar"}
form = MyForm(data=data, instance=instance)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
else:
    print(form.errors)
```

Moving forward it feels like this question is in regards to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68234977/get-non-valid-fields-from-django-form) where you stated in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68234977/get-non-valid-fields-from-django-form#comment120596077_68235000):

> The thing is, the `request` contains data submitted by the user, which
> has to be transformed before added to `MyForm` along with some other
> data

Well you can transform the data in the form too! You can modify the data in the forms `clean` or `clean_<field>` methods as described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute). For example let us say we wanted to add "Hello " before some user submitted data for field `some_field`, we can do it as follows:

```
from django import forms

class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    # Everything as before.
    ...

    def clean_some_field(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['some_field']
        return "Hello " + data
```